# Java code signing certificate expires - TSA does not work?

Tags: java, certificate, code-signing, jnlp

I do have a problem with Java applications (starting via JNLP) are blocked because of expired code signing certificate.

Code Signing Certificate expires on: 2020-10-01

The applications get signed with following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="maven-antrun-signing" default="main">
    <target name="main">
      <signjar
            keypass="KEYPASS"
            storepass="SECRET_PASSWORD"
            alias="ALIAS_NAME_2020"
            tsaurl="http://timestamp.digicert.com"
            keystore="C:\development\certificate\2018.keystore"
            verbose="true">
                <fileset includes="**/*.jar" dir="."/>
      </signjar>
    </target>
</project>
```

Now works everything fine - the applications are starting via JNLP formt the server are working fine.
But when I change the time of the client machine to the future (e.g.: 2020-12-01) I got the problems:

> Application Blocked for Security
> Failed to Validate the certificate.
> The application will not be started.

What I now don't understand is that I thought the TSA (tsaurl="http://timestamp.digicert.com") should solve this as at the point of signing the certificate is valid.

Is is this not true? Or do I use this in a wrong way?

What could I change to get rid of this (configuring the exception for the domain that delivers the JNLP is not an option)?
Could there be an on the fly signing on the server?